# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over (1+x^2)^{n+1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

**The question:**

> Prove $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over (1+x^2)^{n+1}}={1\cdot3\cdot...\cdot(2n-1)\over 2\cdot4\cdot...\cdot2n}\pi$$

**My attempt:**

I've got to a different solution:

$$\begin{align}I:&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over (1+x^2)^{n+1}}=2\pi i\cdot \operatorname{Res}({1\over{(1+z^2)^{n+1}}},i)\\&={2\pi i \over n!} \cdot((z+i)^{-n-1})^{(n)}=...\\&={2\pi i \over n!}(-n-1)(-n-2)...(-2n)\cdot 2i\\&={(-1)^{n}4\pi\over (n!)^2}\cdot (2n)!
\end{align}
$$

In a 'contradiction' to what I need to show.

Comment: The formula in the box is missing a $\pi$ I think.

Comment: You right, I corrected it by multiplying by $\pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in the third line:
$$\begin{align}I:
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty {dx\over (1+x^2)^{n+1}}=2\pi i\cdot \operatorname{Res}\left({1\over{(1+z^2)^{n+1}}},i\right)\\
&={2\pi i \over n!} \cdot((z+i)^{-n-1})^{(n)}=...\\
&={2\pi i \over n!}(-n-1)(-n-2)...(-2n)\cdot (2i)^{\color{red}{-2n-1}}\\
&={(2n)!\over 4^n(n!)^2}\pi={(2n-1)!!\over(2n)!!}\pi.
\end{align}
$$